# fatal error during installation (0x80070643) SQL Server MAnagement Studio: A valid destination folder for the install could not be determined

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am installing the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (17.2).

It was installed before, but I re-install it because I forgot the admin password (shouldn't do this actually).

However, the re-installation is not successful. The same error message occurs:

> fatal error during installation (0x80070643)
>   SQL Server MAnagement Studio: A valid destination folder for the install could not be determined

I've found one solution here

[A valid destination folder for the install could not be determined when installing SQL Server Management Studio 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373324/a-valid-destination-folder-for-the-install-could-not-be-determined-when-installi#)

But it didn't work on my machine. I even couldn't find the BootstrapDir.

Any ideas what I might look for to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: ` but I re-install it because I forgot the admin password (shouldn't do this actually).` ssms doesn't have an admin password,it is just a client used to connect to sqlserver..I assume you forgot password for sqlserver.If this is the cause,there are ways to recover it

Comment: yes it is sql server password. unfortunately, I uninstalled the smss. and I cant re-install it back.

Comment: It seems the path you are trying to provide is not a valid system drive

Answer (score 9):

Sorry for digging up this grave. If anyone has the same problem there is one registry key that blocks the instalation. Copying from this article.
https://help.act.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024248314-Error-A-computer-restart-is-required-or-Reboot-pending-When-Attempting-to-Install-Act-or-the-Microsoft-SQL-Server-ACT7-Instance
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet[00n]\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations.
This key can be a leftover sometimes and it signals the installer that there is a reboot pending after some other instalation. After deleting it installation goes without any problems.

Answer (score 4):

Jumping ahead to 2020, this problem resurfaced for me while installing SSMS version 18. After many other suggestions did not fix the issue, I found that updating the version of Visual Studio Installer (VS 2019) to current version solved the issue. Since this error code shows up in many different install scenarios, but many different MS products also now share pieces with VS, I hope this might help someone else get to a solution faster.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I "resolved" it by installing [SSMS 16.5.3](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=840946), which was successful. I then was able to install SSMS 17.2 without issue. After 17.2 is installed, 16.5.3 can be uninstalled.

Comment: I had been receiving errors repeatedly when trying to install basically any version of Management Studio I could find publicly available from Microsoft's website (18.0, 2014, 2012). Your 16.5.3 installation tip worked perfectly, and I've finally got a working version of SSMS on this machine. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Simply make sure the bellow path is already created and exists on the designated machine!

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\"

Comment: And if not. What then?